# How can i get input type "date" value from html form into java variable and SQL date format?

Tags: java, html, sql, unparseable

I tried to get the value of html input type "date" using request.getParameter() in servlet class, converted it into java date in JDBC Class, then to sql date format.

> but there is this exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
>   date.

This is the HTML tag for date

> input type="date" name="BirthDate"

This is the servlet code to get value from HTML page

```
String bDate = request.getParameter("BirthDate");
```

This is the JDBC Class code to convert it

```
String bbd = user.getBDate();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
java.util.Date bbDate = df.parse(bbd);;
java.sql.Date bDate = new java.sql.Date(bbDate.getTime());
```

Comment: What was typed in the input field? If you are using at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, it’s better to parse into a `LocalDate` using a `DateTimeFormatter`. You can save the `LocalDate` directly to your SQL database, so saving a conversion. Also the two `Date` classes are long outdated and poorly designed, so you are going to have all the advantages.

Comment: A couple of points, A you have three not 4 y's in your simple date format.  B I recommend using LocalDate over Date.  Lastly if you are using this to write sql the sql.Date field will accept the toString of LocalDate in a query.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(                       // As of JDBC 4.2, pass java.time objects to your database.
    … ,
    LocalDate                                        // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .parse(                                          // Convert text to a `LocalDate` object.
        "23/01/2018" ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )  // Specify formatting pattern to match user input.
    )                                                // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
)
```

## java.time

Use only *java.time* classes. Never use `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

```
String input = "23/01/2018" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).